# Not able to detect a TV tuner in Java

Tags: java, jmf

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to get the display of one laptop into a Java application, and for that I'm using an **Enter E-260U TV Tuner** card, but this device is not being detected using the following: `Vector info = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);`.

**This is my code:**

```
Vector info = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
if (info == null)
  System.out.println("No Capture devices known to JMF");
else {
  System.out.println("The following " + info.size()
      + " capture devices are known to the JMF");
  for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++)
    System.out
        .println("\t" + (CaptureDeviceInfo) info.elementAt(i));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: JMF was obsolete about a decade before TV cards were sold. It does not support them (or the resolutions they work in).

Comment: Are there any alternatives which you can suggest? I have found that OpenCV supports TV tuner cards too but in my case i face the same issue

Comment: *"..which you can suggest?"* There is a close reason based around 'asking for software recommendations'.